# wpf drag and drop visually select item

Tags: c#, wpf, select, drag-and-drop

I'm using drag and drop in my program and it works well. But i'm working with a list of words in a listbox and when I select a word and drag it to another listbox the user don't know anymore which word he chose because the 'visually' selection of the item in the first listbox doesn't appear. Does anyone know how I can see the selected item in the listbox? Before I implemented drag and drop, the chosen word got another color when I selected the word, but when I added drag and drop, i don't see it anymore. Can anyone help me?

http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/8408/imgmt.jpg

```
    private void lstAlleTabellen_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        startpoint = e.GetPosition(null);
    }

    private void lstAlleTabellen_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the current mouse position
        System.Windows.Point mousePos = e.GetPosition(null);
        Vector diff = startpoint - mousePos;

        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed &&
            Math.Abs(diff.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance ||
            Math.Abs(diff.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance)
        {
            // Get the dragged ListViewItem
            System.Windows.Controls.ListBox listAlle = sender as System.Windows.Controls.ListBox;
            ListBoxItem listItem =
                FindAnchestor<ListBoxItem>((DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource);
            Tabel tabel=new Tabel();
            try
            {
                // Find the data behind the ListViewItem
                tabel = (Tabel)listAlle.ItemContainerGenerator.
                    ItemFromContainer(listItem);


                // Initialize the drag & drop operation
                DataObject dragData = new DataObject("myFormat", tabel);
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(listItem, dragData, DragDropEffects.Move);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
    }

    private static T FindAnchestor<T>(DependencyObject current) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        do
        {
            if (current is T)
            {
                return (T)current;
            }
            current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
        }
        while (current != null);
        return null;
    }
    private void lstGekozenTabellen_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.Data.GetDataPresent("myFormat") ||sender == e.Source)
        {
            e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
        }
    }

    private void lstGekozenTabellen_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("myFormat"))
            {
                Tabel tabel = e.Data.GetData("myFormat") as Tabel;
                System.Windows.Controls.ListBox listGekozen = sender as System.Windows.Controls.ListBox;
                listGekozen.DisplayMemberPath = "naam";
                listGekozen.SelectedValuePath = "naam";
                listGekozen.Items.Add(tabel);
                lTabellen.Remove(tabel);

                lstAlleTabellen.ItemsSource = null;
                lstAlleTabellen.Items.Clear();
                lstAlleTabellen.ItemsSource = lTabellen;
            }


        }
        catch { }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use styles trigger for this, for example (full solution [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ListViewDragDropManager.aspx)):

```
    <Style x:Key="ListItemStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Style.Resources>
            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MouseOverBrush" StartPoint="0.5, 0" EndPoint="0.5, 1">
                <GradientStop Color="#22000000" Offset="0" />
                <GradientStop Color="#44000000" Offset="0.4" />
                <GradientStop Color="#55000000" Offset="0.6" />
                <GradientStop Color="#33000000" Offset="0.9" />
                <GradientStop Color="#22000000" Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,4" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="Border.BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,0.5" />
        <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" Value="LightGray" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="jas:ListViewItemDragState.IsBeingDragged" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="DemiBold" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="jas:ListViewItemDragState.IsUnderDragCursor" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MouseOverBrush}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```